# Bugsnag setup using multiple API keys

Tags: bugsnag

I have an Android project that needs to have two API keys for bugsnag, so the errors of the new features that are less frequent get redirected to their own project in bugsnag. But the errors don't fire with the second API key as there's only one api key set in the AndroidManifest file.

```
<meta-data android:name="com.bugsnag.android.API_KEY" android:value="****" />
```

Is there a way to fix this? I have rerouting logic in the code to fire the errors from the new feature with the proper API key, but it breaks because that key is not in the AndroidManifest file

Comment: We’d like to investigate this in more detail to assist. Can you raise a support request by contacting support@bugsnag.com. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For future reference:

See https://docs.bugsnag.com/platforms/android/customizing-error-reports/#apikey on how to implement logic like this in Android

As well as this PR outlining the support we have for changing the API key in a callback function to a secondary key, not necessarily listed in Manifest file: https://github.com/bugsnag/bugsnag-android/pull/928

Hope this helps